# Purpose of .wget-hsts file in Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, filesystem, wget

There is a file in my home folder named `.wget-hsts`. Does this file send my data to anywhere? The file content is as follows:

```
# HSTS 1.0 Known Hosts database for GNU Wget.
# Edit at your own risk.
# <hostname>    <port>  <incl. subdomains>  <created>   <max-age>
raw.githubusercontent.com   0   0   1631759053  31536000
github.com  0   1   1631759053  31536000
github-releases.githubusercontent.com   0   0   1631759055  31536000
```

Why and how this file is created? Is it anything harmful?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

[HTTP Strict Transport Security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security), HSTS for short, is a mechanism to protect against certain kinds of attacks. HSTS allows web servers to specify that clients should only connect to them with encrypted connections.

Let's look at an example: You use your web browser to go to `https://www.some-site.com`. Note the `https://` protocol prefix, it's an encrypted connection. If the admin of `some-site.com` has setup HSTS on their server, your webbrowser makes an internal note: "For this domain, only use encrypted connections in the future (until a date specified by the server)". So, if tomorrow you type `http://www.some-site.com` into your browser (note the unencrypted connection, `http://`), your browser will automatically "upgrade" to `https://www.some-site.com`.

As we've seen, your web browser has an internal list with entries like "For domain X, automatically switch to an encrypted connection until date Y". `wget` can handle HSTS as well, and also automatically "upgrade" connections. But `wget` has to store the list we've seen above somewhere, and that's what `.wget-hsts` is for.

According to your `.wget-hsts` file, you used `wget` to download something from `github.com`, for example. The entry was created at the timestamp `1631759053`, and it is valid until the timestamp `31536000`. HSTS will be applied for connections on any port, and it will be applied for connections to any subdomain of `github.com`.

Comment: In easy word , you mean it's safe ?

Comment: @yoMama33 It's not only safe, it's part of your security.